# Qml - ReferenceError: Screen is not defined

Tags: qml

Trying to build a little fotball game as an project in school but I'm having some issues. So when I run the code it says that ReferenceError: Screen is not defined, but accordign to me I have defined it.

This code is just a prototype, going to change the keys to buttons later on so that it can actually work on a phone.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id:root

    width:Screen.width
    height:Screen.height-10
    focus:true

    Keys.onPressed: {

        if(event.key===Qt.Key_Up)
        {
            event.accepted = true;
            player.y=(player.y) - 40

        }
        if(event.Key === Qt.Key_Down){
            event.accepted = true;
            player.y = (player.y)+ 40
           }
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Right)
         { event.accepted=true;
            player.x=(player.x)-40

        }
   if (event.key === Qt.Key_Left)
{event.accepted = true;
       player.x=(player.x) +40
   }

    }

Flickable {
    width:Screen.width
    height:Screen.height
    contentHeight: Screen.height*4
    contentWidth:Screen.width
    interactive:true
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

    Image{
        id: feild
        anchors.fill:parent
        source:"Namnlös.png"
        sourceSize.height:Screen.height*4
        sourceSize.width:Screen.width
        }

    Image {
        id: player
        source:"asd.png"
        x:Screen.width/2
        y:Screen.height/2
    }
}

}
```

So if you run this code you'll only get the player showing up, and then disapear instantly, the field is not shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You lack the Screen import.

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
```

[Screen docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html)

Comment: Thought i added that before...hehe! Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Resizing items to screen is abnormal, you should simply use
[resizeMode property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickview.html#resizeMode-prop)
and anchor all child items inside root item.